# Finding Minimum Distance Between Words in An Array

Tags: java, algorithm

> Example:
>
> WordDistanceFinder finder = new
> WordDistanceFinder(Arrays.asList("the", "quick", "brown", "fox",
> "quick"));
>
> assert(finder.distance("fox","the") == 3);
>
> assert(finder.distance("quick", "fox") == 1);

I have the following solution, which appears to be O(n), but I'm not sure if there is a better solution out there. Does anyone have any idea?

```
String targetString = "fox";
String targetString2 = "the";
double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for(int x = 0; x < strings.length; x++){
    if(strings[x].equals(targetString)){
        for(int y = x; y < strings.length; y++){
            if(strings[y].equals(targetString2))
                if(minDistance > (y - x))
                    minDistance = y - x;
        }
        for(int y = x; y >=0; y--){
            if(strings[y].equals(targetString2))
                if(minDistance > (x - y))
                    minDistance = x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That solution is O(n^2) -- you have nested `for` loops.  And yes, this can be done in O(n), but I'm pretty sure this is homework, so that's all I'll say for now.

Comment: It's an interview question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You solution is `O(N^2)` because you traverse the whole list when finding each word.
First you find the first word and then again traverse the whole list to find the second word.

What you can do is use two variables to keep track of the position of each word and calculate the distance with a **single pass** through the list => `O(N)`.

```
int index1 = -1;
int index2 = -1;
int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int tempDistance = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < strings.length; x++) {
    if (strings[x].equals(targetString)) {
        index1 = x;
    }
    if (strings[x].equals(targetString2)) {
        index2 = x;
    }
    if (index1 != -1 && index2 != -1) { // both words have to be found
        tempDistance = (int) Math.abs(index2 - index1);
        if (tempDistance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = tempDistance;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Distance:\t" + minDistance);
```

Comment: A major problem: Words are allowed to appear more than once (look at the example problem instance), but this code makes no attempt to consider any but the last occurrence.  A minor problem: Because you wrote `else if` instead of just `if`, this won't work if `targetString == targetString2`.

Comment: Well if words are allowed to appear more than once then its its implementation based how to handle this as in, which one of the duplicates to pick as the start/end. I am not sure why you gave me a -1

Comment: For starters, the example contains "quick" twice.  But more generally, if you're given a problem description, you can't just assume constraints that aren't given in the problem!

Comment: I gave you the -1 because *your code gives the wrong answer sometimes* -- specifically, when the nearest occurrences of the 2 input words are not the last occurrence of each.

Comment: I see you have updated your post, but offering the programmer or user the ability to choose which occurrence doesn't solve the problem: "What is the minimum distance between the two given words?"  The task is to make *the program choose* the right occurrences.

Comment: saw what my issue was, i believe i fixed it. thanks for the pointers

Comment: Almost there, but initializing `minDistance` to -1 won't work, because then your last `if` will never be true.  Also, why are you using `double`?

Comment: @ajb: Good points. `minDistance`.  should start out at INT_MAX, or whatever it's called in Java.

Comment: Its all fixed :) I was rushing to answer quickly and i missed the initialization. To answer @ajb's question, I was using `double` because its a habit when using the `Math` class :). Thanks for the pointers fellas

Answer (score 3):

```
function findMinimumWordDistance(words, wordA, wordB) {
  var wordAIndex = null;
  var wordBIndex = null;
  var minDinstance = null;

  for (var i = 0, length = words.length; i < length; i++ ) {
    if (words[i] === wordA) {
      wordAIndex = i;
    }

    if (words[i] === wordB) {
      wordBIndex = i;
    }

    if ( wordAIndex !== null && wordBIndex !== null ) {
      var distance = Math.abs(wordAIndex - wordBIndex);
      if(minDinstance === null || minDinstance > distance) {
        minDinstance = distance;
      } 
    }
  }
  return minDinstance;
}
```

Comment: `function findMinimumWordDistance(words, wordA, wordB)` Some *Java*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class WordDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=in.nextLine();
        String s1=in.nextLine();
        String s2=in.nextLine();
        int index1=-1;
        int index2=-1;
        boolean flag1=false;
        boolean flag2=false;
        int distance=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int answer=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String[] sarray=s.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<sarray.length;i++)
        {
            if(!s1.equals(s2))
            {
                flag1=false; flag2=false;
            }
            if(s1.equals(sarray[i]) && flag1==false)
            {
                index1=i;
                flag1=true;
            }
            else
            if(s2.equals(sarray[i]) && flag2==false)
            {
                    index2=i;
                    flag2=true;
            }
            if(index1!=-1 && index2!=-1)
            {
                distance=Math.abs(index1-index2);
                flag1=false; flag2=false;
            }
            if(distance<answer)
            {
                answer=distance;
            }
        }
        if(answer==Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        {
            System.out.print("Words not found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(answer);
        }
    }
}

//**Test Case 1**: the quick the brown quick brown the frog  (frog brown) **O/P 2**
//**Test Case 2**: the quick the brown quick brown the frog (brown brown) **O/P 2**
//**Test Case 3**: the brown qucik frog quick the (the quick) **O/P 1**
```

Answer (score 0):

Better and simple solution for finding minimum distance between two words in a given paragraph.

```
    String[] strArray = {"the","quick","brown","fox","quick"};
    String str1 = "quick";
    String str2 = "fox";
    int i,startIndex=0,minDistnace=100;
    for( i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
        if(strArray[i].equals(str1)||strArray[i].equals(str2)){
            startIndex = i;         //get the first occurence of either word
            break;
        }
    }
    for(;i<strArray.length;i++){
        if(strArray[i].equals(str1)||strArray[i].equals(str2)){
            //compare every word from that first occurence 
            // if words not same and distance less than minimun distance then update
            if(!strArray[i].equals(strArray[startIndex]) && (i-startIndex)<minDistance){
                minDistance = i-startIndex;
                startIndex =i;
            }
            else{
                startIndex =i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(minDistance);
```

**Time Complexity**: O(n)
**Space COmplexity**: O(1)

Comment: I doubt this compiles. Once corrected, how is it better than [nem035's 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876861/3789665)?

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 iteration.
Very Simple Solution
Assumptions : str1 and str2 are not null. str1 not equal to str2. strs does not contains null;

```
    private static int findShortestDistance(String str1, String str2, String[] strs) {
        int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String temp = null;
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<strs.length; ++i) {
          if(str1.equals(strs[i]) || str2.equals(strs[i])) {
             if(temp != null && !strs[i].equals(temp)) {
                distance = Math.min(distance, i - index);
             }
             temp = strs[i];
             index = i;
           }
        }
     return distance;
    }
```

Comment: `findShortestDistance("the", "fox", new String[]{"the", "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "quick")`

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static Integer getDistance(String first, String second, String given) {
    String[] splitGiven = given.split(" ");
    int firstWord;
    int secondWord;
    int result;
    List<Integer> suspectedDistances = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitGiven.length; i++) {
      if (Objects.equals(splitGiven[i], first)) {
        firstWord = i;
       
        for (int j = 0; j < splitGiven.length; j++) {
          if (Objects.equals(splitGiven[j], second)) {
            secondWord = j;
            
            suspectedDistances.add(secondWord - firstWord);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  
    Collections.sort(suspectedDistances);
    result = suspectedDistances.get(0);
    if ((splitGiven[0].equals(first) || splitGiven[0].equals(second)) &&
        (splitGiven[splitGiven.length - 1].equals(first) || splitGiven[splitGiven.length - 1].equals(second))) {
      result = 1;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: above solution for : 
write a function that will return the minimum distance between the two words from a given string.
Adjacent words will have a distance of 1.

Comment: From `java.util.Collections`, sorting to just get the minimum (or maximum) is costly. Can you spot something more direct in the documentation? (Other answers avoid collecting distances.)

Comment: `above solution for […] return the minimum distance between the two words from a given string` [Document `getDistance()` in your code](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide). *Edit* your post to add information.

Answer (score 0):

`any ideas?`

You "duplicated" code: Keep DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself

```
double
    distance,
    minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
for (int x = 0 ; x < strings.length ; x++)
    if (strings[x].equals(targetString))
        for (int y = 0 ; y < strings.length ; y++)
            if (x != y && strings[y].equals(targetString2)) {
                if (minDistance > (distance = Math.abs(y - x)))
                    minDistance = distance;
                if (x < y)
                    break;
            }
```

You missed opportunities to stop iterating early:

```
minDistance = strings.length;
if (java.util.Arrays.asList(strings).contains(targetString2))
    for (int x = 0 ; x < strings.length ; x++) {
        if (!strings[x].equals(targetString))
            continue;
        for (int y = x, limit = Math.min(strings.length, x + minDistance) ; ++y < limit ; )
            if (strings[y].equals(targetString2)) {
                minDistance = y - x;
                break;  // higher values of y won't decrease y - x
            }
        for (int y = x, limit = Math.max(-1, x - minDistance) ; limit < --y ; )
            if (strings[y].equals(targetString2)) {
                minDistance = x - y;
                break;  // lower values of y won't decrease x - y
            }
        if (minDistance < 2)
            break;
    }
```